# Fedora stuck in grub command line

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, grub, grub2

My pc not starting and asks for selections:

[list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weHyZ.jpg)

After entering command line, i could not find proper boot and grub folder. These are my file system folders:

[folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzQmx.jpg)

[folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mjZL.jpg)

So, how can set proper boot or grub folder and start my pc?

Thanks

Comment: try on the GRUB menu press letter E on your keyboard and find line starting with linux and remove from this line arguments such as quiet splash and add nomodeset and then press F10 to boot

Comment: When type E: load_video ,set gfxpayload=keep, insmod gzio, linux ($root)/vmlinuz... root=UUID=.... ro rootflags=subvol=Root rhgb quiet, initrd ($root)/initframs.... command are showing. I deleted load_video and deleted quiet option. Added nomodeset instead of quiet. But not working still

Comment: If you boot from live USB media (like the Fedora Workstation installation image), can it find your partitions?

Comment: it can not. I solve my problem by installing another os. it deleted all kernel configurations and so started the processes.